# Swedish address input

Tags: forms, input-fields, internationalisation

Can someone let me know how to localize Swedish address input?

After reading documents such as [**this**](http://www.upu.int/fileadmin/documentsFiles/activities/addressingUnit/sweEn.pdf), I understand the address format but is it commonplace to have the postcode input and the locality on the same line in an input form or is more common to have these fields on separate lines.

Please note - I'm interested here in the UI convention for inputting an address 
 rather than the formal system of address labels

Here are some options:

1. Copy the exact address label (do users just "know" what field does what without input labels)

   - [AddressLine1]
   - [AddressLine2]
   - [PostCode] [Locality]
2. Copy order of the address, one element per line (has room from labels)

   - Address 1 [AddressLine1]
   - Address 2 [AddressLine2]
   - Post Code [PostCode]
   - Locality  [Locality]
3. Offer international address input (or is this a no, no!)

   - Address 1 [AddressLine1]
   - Address 2 [AddressLine2]
   - Locality  [Locality]
   - Post Code [PostCode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option 2 with house number separate:

- Street name [street name]
- House number [House number]
- Post Code [PostCode]
- Locality [Locality]

It follows the natural flow the letter does by starting at the most detailed level (street), to the most broad level (country, or locality in this case). You'll need to separate the post code from the locality, because without labels, people will not understand what you want from them. They are used to having each input field specifically asking for 1 piece of information, and city and post code are two different things. I don't think they'll make the connection.

While I'm not Swedish, the Netherlands uses the same format for letters and this is the way we render this digitally.

You can even only ask for postcode and house number to autocomplete the city and streetname if desired and you have the API. Depending on what your request is for, you can save your user some time. The format will then be:

- Post code [Post code]
- House number [House number]

And it will autocomplete:

- Streetname [Streetname]
- Locality [Locality]